# Can we use ために instead of で

Tags: grammar, particle-で, comparative-constructions

As we know, で is used for, referring to the things that we use as an instrument/means to perform an act.

So, my question is can we use "ために...を使う" instead of "で" to highlight that use? If yes, could you please highlight the difference in nuance?

E.g. 1. 私は電車で大学に行く (This means, I use the train to got to college) & 私は大学に行くために電車を使う (Also means, I use the train to go to college)

E.g. 2. 私達は日本語で話す (This means we talk using Japanese); 私達は話すために日本語を使う (will also mean, We talk using Japanese)

ありがとう

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grammar ために is used to say "for the purpose/sake of". When using it to introduce your main clause, it's giving a *reason* for doing the main verb. That's different than で because で just denotes the "means" by which something is done/accomplished.

The use of ために makes the thing or verb in the dependent clause seem much more important and necessary for the main action.

In your second example, the sentence using で (私達は日本語で話す), simply means "We are speaking in Japanese". The sentence using ために (私達は日本語で話す), however, makes it seem like there is no other way to speak unless you use Japanese: "We are using Japanese *so that* we can speak/have a conversation". I would assume that maybe one of you only speaks Japanese so it's your only choice of language to use.

Generally speaking, the example sentences using で sound more natural but there are some situations for the ために ones.

Comment: ありがとう、 私は分かりました。I am keeping this open for more answers